# data attribute is not working in multiple tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the data attribute value , its returning some undefined value .
I think , I am doing something wrong .
Below is my code , Please have a look.

```js
$(document).on("click",".adm tr .link",function(){
  // alert("hii");
  var company_id = $(this).data("id")
  console.log($(this).data("id"));
  // window.location.href = "userCompany.html"
})
```

```html
<?php foreach ($car_listing as $car_listings) { ?>
  <tr data-id="<?php echo $car_listings->company_id;?>">
    <td class="link">
      <img src="<?php echo image($car_listings->image);?>">
    </td>
    <td class="link"><?php echo $car_listings->name;?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try with $(this).attr("data-id")?

Comment: You're missing a document.ready handler, assuming your `<script>` tag is in the `<head>` of the page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `data-id` attribute is defined on the `<tr>` element but your `$(this)` refers to the `<td class="link">` (since you bound the `click` event on `".adm tr .link"`).

Try this instead:

```
var company_id = $this.parent().data('id')
```

See [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 2):

You are not referencing the right element. Find the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `tr` like this

`var company_id=$(this).closest('tr').data("id")`

This way even if the element is nested you will be able to refer the right `tr` tag.

Answer (score 1):

$(this) is pointing to the td, not the tr which has the data-id attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click",".adm tr .link",function(){
  //alert("hii");
  var company_id=$(this).parents('tr').data("id")
   console.log($(this).data("id"));
 // window.location.href = "userCompany.html"
})
</script>
```